# java.net.UnknownHostException when trying to open stream

Tags: android, excel

I'm trying to load xls file with Jexcel API from http://udios.site88.net/Lunch.xls with this code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://udios.site88.net/Lunch.xls");
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    Workbook workBook = null;
    workBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(in);
    Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheet(0);
    Cell cell;
    cell = sheet.getCell(21, 1);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, cell.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG*3).show();
```

But it throws the following Exception:

java.net.UnknownHostException: udios.site88.net
this happens in:
InputStream in = url.openStream();

can anyone help me with that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and make sure that you have internet connection on your device.

**EDIT:** as I try to access the URL in the browser, it seems that this address is blocked due to a Malware.

Comment: I've already set the internet permission but the problem still occurs
thanks

Comment: The problem is somewhere else as it's not working in my device and in the emulator as well

Comment: that's odd, i already download and open it here but i'll check it.